# Completing the Square with a quartic polynomial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, completing-the-square

Find all integers $n$ for which $81\frac{n^4}{4}-2017n^2+81$ is a prime.

I know completing the square helps with this problem, but I'm not how completing the square is going to get me to the right answer.

When I complete the square I get: $(\frac{9}{2}n^2-9)^2-\frac{6609}{4}n^2$

Comment: to get an integer $n$ must be even. Define $n = 2 x.$  The resulting polynomial in $x$ factors as two quadratics, so cannot be prime unless one of the factors is $\pm 1$ This does actually happen with integer $x$

Comment: As a start you might want to think about the parity of $n$ and see if you can get rid of the fractions. The form $(2n-m)^2=4n^2-4nm+m^2$ is often useful with quadratics.

Comment: Dave, you are not sure where to begin with  completing square?

Comment: @DaveEzarik Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Following the hint given in the comments, we need that $n=2k$ and therefore

$$81\frac{n^4}{4}-2017n^2+81=324k^4-8068k^2+81$$

and from $(2n-m)^2=4n^2-4nm+m^2$ we have

$$324k^4-8068k^2+81=[4(9k^2)^2-4\cdot 9k^2\cdot 9+9^2]-88^2k^2$$